# Android drawable resolutions mapping - old and new naming

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I have a problem in mapping between old and new Android drawable resolutions. I have an app with drawable files named:

- drawable
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-large-hdpi
- drawable-large-mdpi
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-sw800dp
- drawable-xhdpi

What are their corresponding in

- ldpi
- mdpi
- hdpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi
- xxxhdpi

Answer (score 0):

Some of them are the same as below, e.g. hdpi = hdpi

Large and sw800dp belong to the screen size and not to the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, none of the resolution modifiers you stated are "new". They have all been around for a while. The other modifiers you currently use are for other properties, not resolution.